# proper update statement in DB2 to avoid transaction log full

Tags: transactions, db2, db2-luw

I would like to update a table with over 2 million records in DB2 running on unix. Is there a way to update in batch size say 5000 rows a time? In Sybase, I can use "set rowcount 5000" like the following:

```html
set rowcount 5000
while ( 1=1 )
begin
 begin tran
  update X set ... where ...
  if (@@error != 0)
    begin
        rollback tran
        return 1
    end
 commit tran

if(  @@rowcount < 5000 ) break
end

set rowcount 0
```

How to do this in DB2? The purpose is try to avoid transaction log full leading to update failure.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options, both involving compound SQL. If there is a way for you to determine what records have been updated and what have not, you could write something like this:

```
BEGIN
  WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourtable WHERE <condition to find records to update>)
  DO
    UPDATE (SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE <condition> FETCH FIRST 5000 ROWS ONLY)
      SET ...; -- updating 5000 rows at a time
    COMMIT;
  END WHILE;
END
```

If you cannot easily distinguish between the updated and not yet updated rows, you could do something like this:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  FOR l AS cur CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR 
   SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE ... FOR UPDATE
  DO
    UPDATE yourtable SET ... WHERE CURRENT OF cur;
    SET i = i + 1;
    IF MOD(i, 5000) = 0 THEN
      COMMIT; -- every 5000 rows
    END IF;
  END FOR;
  COMMIT; -- last set, may be less than 5000 rows
END
```

The latter option obviously is less efficient, because it updates rows one by one, as opposed to sets of 5000 rows.